# Allow uses to adjust the position of their profile pictures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, file-upload, redux

I am building a website and want to include the feature that allows users to adjust the position of their profile picture when uploading (which part of the picture gets displayed by the "img" element). LinkedIn, for example, has this feature. I searched about how to implement the feature but did not find anything helpful. The code below is what I have right now: After the user selects a image file, it will be uploaded to firebase storage, then the web page will be re-rendered and the new image will be displayed on the web page. I am wondering whether anyone can give me a clue about how to add the feature to my existing code. Thanks!

**Client-side code that lets users upload profile images**

```
    state = {
      image: "",
      edit: false
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      const { profile } = this.props;
      this.setState({
        image: profile.image
      })
    }

......

handleUpload = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const image = e.target.files[0];
      const { auth } = this.props;
      this.props.uploadImage(image, auth.uid);
  }

  openFiles = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const input = document.getElementById("imageinput");
      input.click();
  }

......

    render() {

      return (

......

                  <img src={this.state.image ? this.state.image : ditto}></img>
                  <input type="file" id="imageinput" hidden="hidden" onChange={this.handleUpload}></input>
                  <button onClick={this.openFiles}>Upload Profile Image</button>

......
```

**Redux uploadImage action object**

```
export const uploadImage = ( image, userid ) => (dispatch) => {
    firebase.storage().ref('images/'+userid).put(image)
    .then(() => {
        return firebase.storage().ref(`images/`+userid).getDownloadURL()
    })
    .then((image) => {
        firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userid).update({
            image: image
        })
    }).then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: EDIT_SUCCESS });
    })
}
```

Comment: You need to read the image in browser and create feature you want where you have image you drag & drop or resize etc. this is way to big task to have single question about, you can search already create library that do that, like cropper or something like that. With this library you need to get the x y and width height, then you can crop the image in browser (using canvas) and upload updated file or upload whole file and do correction in CSS (e.g.: using background position or something else) you can search how if you don't find anything you can ask question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Will take a look at Cropper.